# Multiple Site-To-Site VPNs to one OpenVPN Server

Tags: vpn, openvpn, site-to-site-vpn, opnsense

I am struggling to setup multiple site-to-site vpns.

I have 3 sites:

- Site A: OpenVPN Server, inside OPNsense, IP Ranges: 192.168.10.0/24
- Site B: Asus Router with Fresh-Tomato, IP Ranges: 192.168.20.0/24
- Site C: Asus Stock Router, IP Ranges: 192.168.30.0/24

I managed to setup an OpenVPN Server in OPNsense with the following:

```
IPv4 Tunnel Network: 10.10.1.0/24
IPv4 Local Network: 192.168.10.0/24,192.168.20.0/24
IPv4 Remote Network: 192.168.20.0/24
```

And also a client specific override for Client B with:

```
IPv4 Remote Network: 192.168.20.0/24
```

With that setup, I was able to connect site B to the server on site A and can access the ips of site A from site B and the other way around. I am not sure if all that configs are needed or if some could be skipped but I was happy to get it working.

Now I also want to add site C as client to site A.

I tried reusing the same OpenVPN server for site C and just extended `IPv4 Local Network`, `IPv4 Remote Network` and added a separate client specific override for the range of C: `192.168.30.0/24`

Uppon doing that, site C fails to connect to A with `Conflicting Routing Rules`.

Is is possible to add multiple site-to-site to one instance of an OpenVPN server at all or does each one need a separate server? If it is possible, what am I missing? Also, is the other configuration ok like this?

Comment: I believe that the "overriding" makes trouble - you have duplicate definition on '192.168.2.0/24'.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I do the same for site B which works.